# Instagram ad error

Tags: android, instagram

I am trying to promote my android app with instagram ads but am getting the following error: "Sorry, but we're having trouble promoting your post and are working to solve the problem. Please try again".

This is not a helpful error. Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for days. I changed the "Audience" to automatic and it worked. I deleted that promotion as I didn't want it to be automatic, and i changed the audience to "create your own" and i put a lot more options in and made it not as specific and it worked. Hope that helps!